# Opening a file from the path mentioned in textpad and notepad++

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, textpad

If I save file paths in textpad or notepad++ like below...

C:/data/a.txt

D:/fgh/b.pdf

And if I want to open these files from textpad and notepad++, there are some shortcut keys. Please provide the same.

Comment: C:\data\a.txt  and D:\fgh\b.pdf...slash is other way in windows. Only txt files will be opened directly in textpad and notepad++...other formats may open with junk chars....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align the mouse pointer on the text and press shortcut keys mentioned below.

C:/data/a.txt

D:/fgh/b.pdf

textpad: Ctrl+shift+g

notepad++: Alt+F5

Answer (score 0):

Put the path of file in notepad++ like

```
C:/data/a.txt
```

Then select it and press Alt+F5. It will open the file in notepad++

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are seeking.

`file://C:/data/a.txt`

`file://D:/fgh/b.pdf`